# Grouped bar chart with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make a plot with Plotly.Below you can see my data.

```
df<-data.frame(
  Country=c('Aruba','Benin','Albania','Aruba','Benin','Albania'),
  Year=c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011),
  share_female=c(0.6315789,0.5833333,0.2500000 ,0.6315789,0.5833333,0.2500000),
  share_male=c(0.36842105,0.41666667,0.75000000,0.36842105,0.41666667,0.75000000))%>%
  data.table()

df$Year<-as.character(df$Year)
df<-melt(df)
df$Country<-as.factor(df$Country)
```

Now I want to plot grouped bar chart with Plotly that showed different color participation of males and females by separate country.

```
GenderShare <- plot_ly(df, x = ~Year , y = ~value ,
                                 type = 'bar',
                                 name = ~Country)
         
GenderShare
```

So share between males and females by separate country is visible only with however with the mouse.
[image]

But this chart is not what I am looking for. Instead of this, I need to have the name of the country below each bar in a vertical direction plus a share of males and females with different colors(e.g., blue for males and red for females) in the legend.

So can anybody help how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this?:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("share_female", "share_male"),
               names_to = "Gender", values_to = "Share") %>%
  mutate(Gender = sub("share_", "", Gender),
         Country_Gender = paste0(Country, " ", Gender))

plot_ly(df_long, x = ~Year, y = ~Share, color = ~Country_Gender,
                       type = 'bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. Please see my chart.  I need the name of the country below each bar on the x-axis and the different colors for each bar for females and males in the legend.

Comment: Ok. please see my new answer.